# Crazy ambiguous thing

Tags: c++, qt

Today I've discovered a crazy thing. It reproduces under several platforms (Windows, macOS, Android).

I use Qt, and have the following "problematic" class:

```
class AbstractUiDownloadInfo :
        public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AbstractUiDownloadInfo(
            const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo> &info,
            const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadRunTimeInfo> &info2,
            QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit AbstractUiDownloadInfo(
            const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo> &info,
            QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit AbstractUiDownloadInfo(
            const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadRunTimeInfo> &info2,
            QObject *parent = nullptr);
```

I also have this struct:

```
struct AbstractNewDownloadRequest
{
    QVector<QSharedPointer<AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo>> infos;
};
```

So, I'm trying to use it:

```
// somewhere before
AbstractNewDownloadRequest m_request;
// then:
auto info = m_request.infos[index];
return new AbstractUiDownloadInfo(info);
```

Gives me the following errors:

```
..\..\fdm-qml\common\abstractui\abstractuinewdownloadrequest.cpp(30): error C2668: 'AbstractUiDownloadInfo::AbstractUiDownloadInfo': ambiguous call to overloaded function
c:\work\source\fdm-qml\common\abstractui\abstractuidownloadinfo.h(42): note: could be 'AbstractUiDownloadInfo::AbstractUiDownloadInfo(const AbstractUiDownloadInfo &)'
c:\work\source\fdm-qml\common\abstractui\abstractuidownloadinfo.h(24): note: or       'AbstractUiDownloadInfo::AbstractUiDownloadInfo(const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadRunTimeInfo> &,QObject *)'
c:\work\source\fdm-qml\common\abstractui\abstractuidownloadinfo.h(21): note: or       'AbstractUiDownloadInfo::AbstractUiDownloadInfo(const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo> &,QObject *)'
..\..\fdm-qml\common\abstractui\abstractuinewdownloadrequest.cpp(30): note: while trying to match the argument list '(QSharedPointer<AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo>)'
```

But the following code works fine:

```
QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo> info =
            m_request.infos[index];
return new AbstractUiDownloadInfo(info);
```

What is going on?

Addition #1.

**StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post code here anymore so I post screenshots.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: hmm... as i thought ambiguous != don't know....

Comment: How can it at all call AbstractUiDownloadInfo::AbstractUiDownloadInfo(const AbstractUiDownloadInfo &) constructor for my argument's type??

Comment: "StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post code here anymore" - now this is something unusual... what happens if you post code as text?

Comment: @VTT he probably hit this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310791/it-looks-like-your-post-is-mostly-code-please-add-some-more-details

Comment: This question really needs a clearer title.

Comment: spectras, yep, as I said in question, SO did not allow me to post more code. But some people prefer to condemn without a judge..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is absence of `const` qualifier in `QSharedPointer<AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo>`argument. So in the first case shared pointer need to go through an extra conversion which turns to be ambiguous.

I guess this will be a simplified example. Template constructor of `foo` makes both variants of `bar` a viable overloads so ambiguity occurs even though actual attempt to construct `foo<char const *>` from `foo<int>` will lead to template instantiation failure:

```
template<typename T> struct
foo
{ 
    T m_v;

    foo(void) {}

    foo(foo<T> const &) {}

    template<typename X>
    foo(foo<X> const &): m_v{X{}} {}
};

void bar(foo<int const>) {}

void bar(foo<char const *>) {}

int main()
{
    foo<int> f;
    bar(f);
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nn4i7IOCnXJSS8Bc)

Comment: Yep,but anyway, how can it be ambiguous??

Comment: What constructor it can call at all except the one which can accept only 1 parameter: const QSharedPointer<const AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo> &info ???

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev We would have to see how `AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo` and `AbstractDownloadRunTimeInfo` are defined.

Comment: These are completely different and independent structures. They does not know about each other.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev They all derive from `QObject` I believe?

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev It is ambiguous because, when resolving an overloaded function call, the best match is considered depending on what type of conversions are needed to be performed to make the argument and the parameter match. Conversion to const and casting to those types are considered equivalent casts, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: AbstractDownloadPersistentInfo  is a very big stucture, I don't want to post it here. AbstractDownloadRunTimeInfo  is a small one...

Comment: Nope, they're not QObject-derived

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev You can post just basic definition of it, not the entire structure.

Comment: SO doesn't allow me to post it - it says my post is most of code.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev You should add it to the question by editing it, not into the comments (as I assume you tried).

Comment: Added. Please see addition #1.